# How do I pull specific information from an RSS feed in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, scripting, rss, filtering

I trying to write a script that can pull information from a webpage that only contains input that the user provided.

I am using the news site independents rss feed to parse.

```
    $url = 'http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/rss'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -OutFile c:\Scripts\worldnews.xml


[xml]$Content = Get-Content C:\Scripts\worldnews.xml


$Feed = $Content.rss.channel


# User Input field
$UserTerm = Read-Host 'Enter a Term'


ForEach ($msg in $Feed.Item){


   [PSCustomObject]@{


     'Source' = "News"

    'Title' = $msg.title

    'Link' = $msg.link

    'Description' = $msg.description



   }#EndPSCustomObject

  }#EndForEach
```

what do i need to add so that this script will only display results that include the input that the user has given? e.g. if the user types 'Police' in the user input then the script will only display the articles that have 'Police' written in the title.

I have tried an if statement but i'm unsure on the correct syntax

```
if(msg.title -match $UserTerm) {
```

How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a [where clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) on the title in your foreach loop, like so:

```
$url = 'http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/rss'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -OutFile c:\scripts\worldnews.xml
[xml]$Content = Get-Content C:\scripts\worldnews.xml
$Feed = $Content.rss.channel

# User Input field
$UserTerm = Read-Host 'Enter a Term'
ForEach ($msg in $Feed.Item | ?{$_.Title.Contains($userTerm)})
{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Source' = "News"
    'Title' = $msg.title
    'Link' = $msg.link
    'Description' = $msg.description
    }#EndPSCustomObject
}#EndForEach
```

If you wanted to do an if statement, then you would say

```
if($msg.Title.Contains($userTerm))
```

Or you could use the `-like` operator with a wild card like so

```
if($msg.Title -like "*$($userTerm)*")
```